# Dump IR after each LLVM optimization (each pass), both LLVM IR passes and backend debugging

Tags: debugging, compiler-construction, clang, llvm

I want to find some debugging options for Clang/LLVM which work like GCC's [-fdump-tree-all-all](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#index-fdump-tree), [-fdump-rtl-all](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#index-fdump-rtl-all), and [-fdump-ipa-all-all](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#index-fdump-ipa).

Basically, I want to have an LLVM [IR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared) dump before and after each optimization pass. Also, it can be useful to have all dumps of the [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) from Clang and all phases of code generation (backend phases, Selection [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), ISEL-SDNode, register allocation, and MCInsts).

I was able to find only the Clang's `-ccc-print-phases`, but it will only print high-level phases names, e.g., preprocess-compile-assemble-link; but no any dump of IR.

Also there is *[Life of an instruction in LLVM](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/life-instruction-llvm)* paper with `-cc1-ast-dump` option to dump Clang ASTs, but I want more, especially for code generation.

Comment: Hmm, there are "`-print-after-all`  - Print IR after each pass; 
  -print-before-all - `Print IR before each pass`" for IR phases, but how to get dumps from backend?

Comment: You can print debug info from backend phases yourself, eg. `CGDebugInfo` object from codegen.

Comment: mishr, Isn't CGDebugInfo from clang IR emitter, not from llvm backend? I want to get info from LLVM IR-to-machine code backend (codegen)

Comment: True. Maybe this will help. See the last 2 sections, and maybe you need to chase how it was done. http://nondot.org/sabre/LLVMNotes/DebugInfoVariableInfo.txt

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems that you've already discovered how to do dumps on the Clang AST level and LLVM IR level. For code generation, the following are useful:

`-debug` for a detailed textual dump of instruction selection and later stages. Also, the `-view*-dags` show (pop-up) DAGs:

```
llc -help-hidden | grep dags
```

Output:

```
-view-dag-combine-lt-dags  - Pop up a window to show dags before the
                             post legalize types dag combine pass
-view-dag-combine1-dags    - Pop up a window to show dags before
                             the  first dag combine pass
-view-dag-combine2-dags    - Pop up a window to show dags before the
                             second dag combine pass
-view-isel-dags            - Pop up a window to show isel dags
                             as they are selected
-view-legalize-dags        - Pop up a window to show dags before legalize
-view-legalize-types-dags  - Pop up a window to show dags
                             before legalize types
-view-misched-dags         - Pop up a window to show MISched
                             dags after they are processed
-view-sched-dags           - Pop up a window to show sched
                             dags as they are processed
-view-sunit-dags           - Pop up a window to show SUnit dags
                             after they are processed
```

These may not show up if you haven't configured and compiled LLVM with [Graphviz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz) support.

Comment: Eli, can you add information about clang and IR dumps into your answer too?

Comment: And -print-machineinstrs may be useful. My llc from llvm 3.2 doesn't have any of `-view-*-dags`.

Comment: @osgx: see my edit w.r.t. not having `-view-*`. As for other dumps, feel free to edit my answer with the information you've already pasted into the questions and comments :)

Answer (score 6):

It is not fully about your question, but to see the passes applied, you can do:

`clang test.c -Ofast -march=core-avx2 -mllvm -debug-pass=Arguments`

You will see something like:

`Pass Arguments:  -datalayout -notti -basictti -x86tti -targetlibinfo -jump-instr-table-info -targetpassconfig -no-aa -tbaa -scoped-noalias -basicaa -collector-metadata -machinemoduleinfo -machine-branch-prob -jump-instr-tables -verify -verify-di -domtree -loops -loop-simplify -scalar-evolution -iv-users -loop-reduce -gc-lowering -unreachableblockelim -consthoist -partially-inline-libcalls -codegenprepare -verify-di -stack-protector -verify -domtree -loops -branch-prob -machinedomtree -expand-isel-pseudos -tailduplication -opt-phis -machinedomtree -slotindexes -stack-coloring -localstackalloc -dead-mi-elimination -machinedomtree -machine-loops -machine-trace-metrics -early-ifcvt -machinelicm -machine-cse -machine-sink -peephole-opts -dead-mi-elimination -processimpdefs -unreachable-mbb-elimination -livevars -machinedomtree -machine-loops -phi-node-elimination -twoaddressinstruction -slotindexes -liveintervals -simple-register-coalescing -misched -machine-block-freq -livedebugvars -livestacks -virtregmap -liveregmatrix -edge-bundles -spill-code-placement -virtregrewriter -stack-slot-coloring -machinelicm -edge-bundles -prologepilog -machine-block-freq -branch-folder -tailduplication -machine-cp -postrapseudos -machinedomtree -machine-loops -post-RA-sched -gc-analysis -machine-block-freq -block-placement2 -stackmap-liveness -machinedomtree -machine-loops`

Comment: Zinovy, thank you, it can be helpful too. What is the mininal version of clang/llvm to use the "`-debug-pass=Arguments`"?

Comment: `-mllvm -debug-pass=Structure` is even nicer. It includes the output of `-debug-pass=Arguments`, but also dumps a tree of optimizations applied with human-readable names.

Comment: Re `-debug-pass=Arguments`: Not [`-fdebug-pass-arguments`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-fdebug-pass-arguments)? Did it change in a later version?

Answer (score -4):

I am using `llvm-gcc-4.2` on [Mac OS X v10.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) (Mountain Lion) and `-fdump-tree-all` works.

```
gcc  -fdump-tree-all -o test file1.c file2.c file1.h -I  .
```

Comment: Does it output LLVM IR core, or only GCC's internal representation?