# Compilers - stop in the middle of the process

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

I just started to learn about compilers, and I wondered - is there a way to tell GCC (or any other compiler) to stop in the middle of the process, and give me a file with the current state (for example - a token tree)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800230/how-can-i-dump-an-abstract-syntax-tree-generated-by-gcc-into-a-dot-file

Comment: Recent news: [GCC Melt](http://gcc-melt.org) supports a lot of what you are going to want.

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes!

When building a compiler, often one of your most important debugging tools is to see the current representation of the program, or even better, the states throughout compilation, so that when a transformation goes wrong -- i.e. a compiler bug -- it can be identified.

Dumping all the state of a compiler can be a lot however; Even just the intermediate representation for a large function can be tens-of-thousands of lines of plain-text. Then, there's also all the associated data structures: Control-flow graphs, dependency information, symbols etc.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904440/dump-ir-after-each-llvm-optimization-each-pass-both-llvm-ir-passes-and-backen) for some more detail on answers for LLVM and GCC.