# Generate an optimized AST using clang and libclang

Tags: clang, compiler-optimization, libclang

I want to apply clang optimizations to a source file then generate its AST.
I tried passing `-O3` flag but it seems that it is ignored.

For example I assume that for this snipped of program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  int a = 5 + 5;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { }
  printf("%i\n", a);
  return 0;
}
```

Many optimizations can be applied, like removing the for loop converting 5 + 5 to 10.

When I dump the AST using `clang -O3 -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only a.c` I get the same AST without the optimization flag.

My goal is create a TranslationUnit with flag optimizations passed.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe optimizations don't result into another AST? See if what you are looking for are [IR dumps after each llvm optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904440/dump-ir-after-each-llvm-optimization-each-pass-both-llvm-ir-passes-and-backen#17929976).

Comment: Not really. What I am looking for is an optimized AST.

Comment: First, the program is lowered from AST to IR. Second, optimization is performed on the IR. There is no such thing as 'optimized AST'.